# How can I stop a Device.StartTimer() when I change pages?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView that I am updating every 5 seconds using Device.StartTimer() and I would like to stop the timer when it leaves the ViewModel page. as you must intuit necsito do this because Device.StartTimer () is global and even when I change the page is still updating my ListView, how can I make ViewModel know that I'm changing pages?

This is part of my ViewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection sensors;

public ObservableCollection<PcData> Sensors
{
    get { return sensors; }
    set
    {
        sensors = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}


public MonitoringTabsViewModel(string idCode, string description)
{
    Description = description;
    LoadSensors(idCode);
    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () =>
    {
        RefreshSensors(idCode);
        return true;
    });
}

private async void LoadSensors(string idCode)
{
    Sensors = new ObservableCollection<PcData>(await App.WebApiManager.GetCurrentStatusDeviceAsync(idCode));
}

private async void RefreshSensors(string idCode)
{
    Sensors = null;
    Sensors = new ObservableCollection<PcData>(await App.WebApiManager.GetCurrentStatusDeviceAsync(idCode));
}
```

In the end I have come to the following implementation which actually does what I wanted:
ViewModel:

```
public class MonitoringTabsViewModel : Notificable
{
    public string IdCode { get; set; }

    public bool InPage { get; set; }

    private string description;

    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set
        {
            description = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<PcData> sensors;

    public ObservableCollection<PcData> Sensors
    {
        get { return sensors; }
        set
        {
            sensors = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public MonitoringTabsViewModel(string idCode, string description)
    {
        IdCode = idCode;
        Description = description;
        LoadSensors(idCode);
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MonitoringView>(this, "OnAppearing", (sender) =>
        {
            InPage = true;
        });
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MonitoringView>(this, "OnDisAppearing", (sender) =>
        {
            InPage = false;
        });
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimerCallBack);
    }

    private bool TimerCallBack()
    {
        if (InPage)
        {
            RefreshSensors(IdCode);
            MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<MonitoringView>(this, "OnAppearing");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<MonitoringView>(this, "OnDisAppearing");
            return false;
        }
    }

    private async void LoadSensors(string idCode)
    {
        Sensors = new ObservableCollection<PcData>(await App.WebApiManager.GetCurrentStatusDeviceAsync(idCode));
    }

    private async void RefreshSensors(string idCode)
    {
        Sensors = null;
        Sensors = new ObservableCollection<PcData>(await App.WebApiManager.GetCurrentStatusDeviceAsync(idCode));
    }

}
```

View:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    MessagingCenter.Send<MonitoringView>(this, "OnAppearing");
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    MessagingCenter.Send<MonitoringView>(this, "OnDisAppearing");
}
```

There are still two things that concern me:
1. I do not know if the management I'm giving to the MessagingCenter is appropriate, as you can see I'm unsubscribing in my TimerCallBack method, by putting breakpoints in the two calls to the unsubscribe method I see that while the timer is running every 5 seconds The unsubscribe method of the onAppearing message is still called.
2. Although this implmentacion works, I still have the problem that when sleeping the application or put it in the background is still running my method RefreshSensors () and I would like to be in segudno flat also stop the execution.

Could someone give me ideas of these two concerns that I still have?

Answer (score 1):

`Page` has 2 indicator methods `OnAppearing()` & `OnDisappearing()` depends on your setup you should hookup to this events and notify the `ViewModel`.

This can be done in multiple ways:

- `Page` may have a direct or indirect reference (BindingContext) to the `ViewModel` so just hookup.
- You can use `MessagingCenter`.
- If you have a custom handmade `NavigationService` you could hookup there.
- Use existing MVVM Framework, there are plenty of them and most of them support this scenario

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I will try with the first two forms, although I like it more as it sounds to use the MessagingCenter to send messages, so far I discard the fourth since I do not use a MVVM Framework yet.

Comment: `MessagingCenter` can be tricky, don't forget to unsubscribe. If you find my answer helpful please accept and upvote.

Comment: Do you have any recourse about the dangers of the MessagingCenter? or something about good practices when using it? A small example of how to apply it to my situation would not be bad and I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I am trying to do this with the MessaginCenter but again I have come to a standstill.
In my View I use the MessagingCenter to send a message of OnAppearing and OnDisApprearing respectively but I can not find the correct way to gather these messages inside Device.StartTimer () in my ViewModel depending on which message is collected return true or false to repeat or not the timer. Any ideas ?

Comment: Sounds like you have a specific problem which does not fall in the context of your original question, I would recommend to ask a new question which should include what you have tried so far and what is the exact problem you have. Official documentation is a good resource: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center

Comment: I will do what you indicate, I have looked at the documentation but it seems to me something small and it does not clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

> I still have the problem that when sleeping the application or put it
>   in the background is still running my method RefreshSensors ()

If you look in you `App.xaml.cs` file, you'll find the following methods:

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
    // Handle when your app starts
}

protected override void OnSleep()
{
    // Handle when your app sleeps
}

protected override void OnResume()
{
    // Handle when your app resumes
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
Do you have any idea how to know since View is putting my app to sleep? this for only if you are sleeping from the View that I am interested in sending the message.
You have an idea of how the implementation of the MessaginCenter could be done, I do not want to use it in a bad way, this referring to dodne I have to do the unsubscription.